# Error: package “estimate” is installed before R 4.0.0, please re-install it

Tags: r, package, r-forge

I'm using R4.3.1,and I manually installed a package 'estimate' from [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=2237). I have installed corresponding Rtools.
However, when I try to library this package, there is a problem:

```r
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘estimate’:
 package ‘estimate’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Then I try to do the following, but the problem persists when I library it:

```r
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

P.S. I have re-installed it and any of other packages, but the same problem still exists

What is happening and what should I do?

I have re-install it and any of other packages,but the same problem still exists.I have never used past version of R

What happening and what should I do?

Comment: Which version of Rtools have you installed?

Comment: You are likely _reinstalling the same pre-made binary_ from R-Forge when you should be reinstalling from _source_ to create a fresh binary.  Unfortunately, source builds can be harder, depending on ther package at hand and its dependencies and/or use of source code and possibly external libraries.

Comment: @Roland Rstools43